# Filter entities on a sub-entity property in Google Datastore query

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

My Datastore entities are going to have properties of [embedded entity type](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities).

After I save them as following (**I'm using gcloud v0.27.0**):

```
dataset.save([{
    key: dataset.key({ path: ['MyKind', 1] }),
        data: {
            foo: 'bar',
            zxc: {
                nested: {
                    foobar: 32
                }
            }
        }
    }, 
    {
        key: dataset.key({ path: ['MyKind', 2] }),
        data: {
            foo: 'a string',
            zxc: {
                nested: {
                    foobar: 132
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ], function(error) { console.log(error); });
```

**Is there any way to query entities that, say, have `zxc.nested.foobar=132`?**

I run query like on the picture below and it shows no result.

[image]

Comment: It's a Node.js snippet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by joining the property names with dots and using that joined string as the property name in the query.

In the Cloud Datastore v1beta3 API, the JSON request would look like:

```
{
  "query": 
  {
    "kinds": 
    [
      {
        "name": "MyKind"
      }
    ],
    "filter": 
    {
      "propertyFilter": 
      {
        "property": 
        {
          "name": "zxc.nested.foobar"
        },
        "operator": "EQUAL",
        "value": 
        {
          "integerValue": "132"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note in order for a result to appear, each of the properties must be indexed. This is the case by default in the JSON API:

```
{
  "key": 
  {
    "path": 
    [
      {
        "kind": "MyKind",
        "id": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "properties": 
  {
    "zxy": 
    {
      "entityValue": 
      {
        "properties": 
        {
          "nested": 
          {
            "entityValue": 
            {
              "properties": 
              {
                "foobar": 
                {
                  "integerValue": "132"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Datastore client libraries typically also index properties by default, but some older versions of `gcloud-node` (e.g. 0.27.0) may not.

Comment: They should -- if they're not working for you, can you provide details of what you've tried?

Comment: I've updated the question, please could you have a look?

Comment: I think you want zxc.nested.foobar=132 (instead of =32)?

Comment: neither zxc.nested.foobar=132 nor zxc.nested.foobar=32 works

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce this issue in my own project. Can you send your project ID and the key of the entity you expect the query to return to eddavisson@google.com so I can take a closer look?

Answer (score 4):

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore');
// Your Google Cloud Platform project ID
const projectId = 'your-project-id';
// Creates a client
const datastore = new Datastore({
  projectId: projectId,
});
let query = datastore.createQuery('MyKind');
let query = query.filter('xyz.foobar', '=', 32);
query.run()
  .then( (results) => {
    //do your thing
  });
```

I know I'm late, but in case somebody needs it, here it goes. It works for me with `"@google-cloud/datastore": "^1.3.4"`

Comment: What is `query_facturas`? It is not defined in your example code.